# Qt: connect a signal after a request is sent in QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I was checking some simple examples of using QNetworkAccessManager and I found this (Assuming that manager is a QNetworkAccessManager:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.someserver.com"));

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
    this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
    this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
```

As far as I understand, the call to manager->get will send out a GET request. The slots to handle the answer to that request, however, are connected only *after* the call is sent, which does not seems to make sense for me. Here my question:

- isn't it a problem to connect the slots to the signals after the request is done? Can it happen that the request is done and the signals are emitted before the connection takes place, and hence, that the signals are missed and never processed by the corresponding slots?

Thanks!

L.

UPDATE: As pointed out by cyber_raj, this question has been already answered here: [Qt signal slot connection - QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627573/qt-signal-slot-connection-qnetworkaccessmanager)

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.
The get call is asynchronous: 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details

QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives, and runs 6 asynchronous tasks per time.
So there's no much room to an error as you point.

But if you're afraid you can try the first example, connecting the signals of the manager:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

Comment: The page you posted reads: "6 requests are executed in parallel for one host/port combination in http". If I get this correctly, this means that if less than 6 request are being processed for the same host/port combination, my request would be executed right away, so I think the question remains.