# QNetworkReply Never emit a finished signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a simple qt network application. I try to read the data from the `QNetworkReply` but it seems that the finished signal never emit. What happens?

```
QByteArray utils::Login(QString account)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest* request = new QNetworkRequest();
    request->setUrl(QUrl(Urls::loginUrl));

    request->setRawHeader("Host", "10.136.2.5");
    request->setRawHeader("Referer", "http://10.136.2.5/jnuweb/");
    request->setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    request->setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    request->setRawHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    request->setRawHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    request->setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");

    QJsonObject* requestContent = new QJsonObject();
    requestContent->insert("user", QJsonValue(account));
    requestContent->insert("password", QJsonValue(Urls::initPassword));

    QNetworkReply* reply = manager-> post(*request, QJsonDocument(*requestContent).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]()
    {
        QList<QPair<QByteArray, QByteArray>> responses = reply -> rawHeaderPairs();
        qDebug() << responses;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, what happens after the function is called? Is there any event loop in that thread?

Comment: @AlexanderVX Thanks for reply, I started debugging it but the program just paused in connect function. No output from QDebug. There is no such an even loop I think.

Comment: Paused on itself? Cannot pass `connect`? Or it passes and terminates? It must have an event loop for posting the network data: either in that thread or GUI thread always has event loop but it is hidden in QApplication. Do you have at least `app.exec()` for the running? I suspect you use main thread.

Comment: If do not use lambda signal & slot everything remains same?

Comment: Also I wonder if you have access to the server and if you can tell us this request goes to server?

Comment: It seems more logical to connect prior to posting the request.

Comment: It is possible that `finished` is emitted before your `connect` statement. Try connecting the [`finished` signal of `QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) and see what happens.

Comment: Well, after more investigation, I changed the return type to void and successfully solve this problem. But I just do not know why.

Comment: @thuga It depends, because Qt events loop won't execute slots if the function is not terminated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627573/qt-signal-slot-connection-qnetworkaccessmanager) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370840/qt-connect-a-signal-after-a-request-is-sent-in-qnetworkaccessmanager).